# Mitm Proxy using c# SslStream issues when doing directly from host file

Tags: tls, proxy, .net, tcp

Im trying to create a local windows MITM proxy with C# to deal with a now unsupported application from a company that no longer exists.

The Proxy has to only service one HTTPS domain which is being done by creating a proxy that listens on the local address:port 127.0.0.1:443.

An entry in the host file is then created i.e. 127.0.0.1 my.single.domain.com.

If I was to connect to this with a browser using its own proxy setting and having no host entry, the browser will send a "CONNECT...etc" to the proxy.

There are many examples for this and I can get this to work fine from these examples. (Titanium.Web.Proxy etc).

When using a host file as described above the ssl/tls handshake is initiated immediately rather than a "CONNECT....etc" being sent. This is because the browser now rightly believes that 127.0.0.1 is the actual server.

Im really stuggling to find a good example of how to deal with this using the C# SslStream option. Most are for simple client server demos and frankly most dont work including MSDNs own examples.

My specific requirement is a browser navigating to

URI: HTTPS:\\my.single.domain.com\ but no other domain to use this proxy so use the host file. (A port forwarder isnt being used because of reasons out of my control)

Where I am able to intercept (MITM) the passing data.

Do I have to create two SslStream connections now?? One to deal with the browser and then a second one to deal with the server.

Just a good basic example would be cool :-)

Comment: This is purely a programming question and should be moved to stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Tag me when this gets migrated to stackoverflow and I'll write you an answer.

Comment: I wasnt sure if I could move it so Ive just recreated it there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198931/mitm-proxy-using-c-sharp-sslstream-issues-when-doing-directly-from-host-file

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been manually migrated by the user. For future reference, high-rep users can vote to move questions to predefined targets as well as close questions. We were going to do that, but it looks like that's not needed now :)